# How to show recently views items like eBay in iOS app

Tags: ios

I am developing an eCommerce app for iOS. I want to display recently viewed products in one of my app's views. I want to do the same thing that eBay did in their iOS app. Whenever I viewed some product or searched for a product, it showed in a recently-viewed table.

How can I do this in my iOS app? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of whatever products the user views or searches. Keep a list of product ids or whatever is appropriate. Store this list in NSUserDefaults or a database depending on your needs so the data is available each time the app is run.

Use this list to display those products in your "recently viewed products" view.

Comment: Thanks maddy for answer. I was thinking the approach of SQLite only. But I thought if there is any other solution.

Comment: SQLite has its uses. But if you only need to store a handful (or even a few hundred) of product ids, SQLite is overkill.

Comment: eBay App shows the recently viewed Items including the ones not just viewed from the iOS app, but also the ones viewed from eBay web site( actually through all media). I wish there was an ALI call that retrieves this list.